# How to dynamically enable/disable entire overflow menu?

Tags: android, fragment, material-design, android-toolbar

I would like to enable/disable the entire overflow menu in my Toolbar at runtime according to certain user actions. This is all within the same fragment. I tried just returning out of onPrepareOptionsMenu() if the condition holds, which hides the three dot icon as soon as the user touches it. However, I can't figure out how to then show the options menu again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu()` invokes `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` again, where you can load/not load the menu based on your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add one more thing if you want to show or hide the menu again without even inflating them. You can use oncreateoptions menu parameter like this

Menu overflow;

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    this.overflow = menu;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and then make a function to show or hide any menu item according to the index. for e.g.

```
 public void hideorShowMenuItems(boolean bool){
       overflow.getItem(1).setVisible(bool);
       overflow.getItem(2).setVisible(bool);
       overflow.getItem(3).setVisible(bool);

    }
```